# Prevent notifications from coming back after being dismissed

Tags: notifications

I'm using a Galaxy Nexus which runs Android 4.3 Jelly Bean. Lately, I have been very annoyed with notifications from apps I have installed (like WhatsApp, Viber, or even missed calls) which keep coming back every ten minutes even after I dismiss them.

Can resetting my phone solve this issue, or are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable notifications on a per-app basis by going to `Settings > Apps > APP_NAME` and unchecking 'Show notifications'